# Odoo project agile jira importer addon installation error

Tags: docker, jira, odoo, odoo-11

I'm trying to add [this app](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/11.0/project_agile_jira) to my Odoo 11 addons. I'm running it in a docker container.

It has been successfully added and updated into my app list. But when getting to install it, I get this log in the Odoo GUI (`Unable to install module "project_agile_jira" because an external dependency is not met: No module named Jira`)

And this log in the terminal:

```
2020-04-16 11:10:41,747 1 INFO Nilecode odoo.addons.base.module.module: ALLOW access to module.button_immediate_install on ['project_agile_jira'] to user m.mahdi@nilecode.com #1 via 172.17.0.1

2020-04-16 11:10:41,747 1 INFO Nilecode odoo.addons.base.module.module: User #1 triggered module installation

2020-04-16 11:10:41,748 1 INFO Nilecode odoo.addons.base.module.module: ALLOW access to module.button_install on ['project_agile_jira'] to user m.mahdi@nilecode.com #1 via 172.17.0.1

2020-04-16 11:10:42,103 1 INFO Nilecode werkzeug: 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Apr/2020 11:10:42] "POST /web/dataset/call_button HTTP/1.1" 200 -

202
```

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You miss a dependency mostly some libs on your system, to install this module. Which exactly i don't know. Maybe a python lib called "jira" (i know what Jira is, but i dont know about a lib for it).

Comment: Note that I'm using docker containerized app

Comment: Then the dependency is missing in your container. So nothing really changed to my last comment ;-)

Comment: Got it. Thanks
Could you tell me how to install it into that container ?

Comment: Sorry but i don't know how you use Docker and how this lib has to be installed. Just add that information to your question and maybe someone can help. Also try to add tags for docker or docker-compose (if you use it). EDIT: with information i mean how you use docker and how the lib is called (should be in the Manifest file of the module).

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot!